# Working with namespaced payloads in Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js

I'm working on a project where the request and response payloads are all namespaced. For example:

```
{
    'SourceMachine':{
        'Host':'some value',
        'Description':'some value',
        'UserName':'some value',
        'Password':'some value'
    }
}
```

To be able to do get() and set() on the individual fields, I overrode the parse method in my "source_model" like so:

```
parse : function(response, xhr) {
    return response.SourceMachine;
}
```

That's all well and good. But the issue is this: When I want to do a POST or PUT operation, I have to get the Host, Description, UserName and Password attributes into the SourceMachine namespace. Basically what I've been doing is copying the model attributes to a temporary object, clearing out the model, then saving as follows:

```
var tempAttributes = this.model.attributes;
this.model.clear();
this.model.save({SourceMachine: tempAttributes});
```

This works, but it screams of KLUGE! There's got to be a better way of working with namespaced data. Thanks!

**Update**

I've now created a require.js module for a base model that I'll be using for all the models in my app, since they all rely on namespaced data:

```
define(function() {
    return Backbone.Model.extend({
        /**
         * Adding namespace checking at the constructor level as opposed to
         * initialize so that subclasses needn't invoke the upstream initialize.
         * @param attributes
         * @param options
         */
        constructor : function(attributes, options) {
            //Need to account for when a model is instantiated with
            //no attributes. In this case, we have to take namespace from
            //attributes.
            this._namespace = options.namespace || attributes.namespace;

            //invoke the default constructor so the model goes through
            //its normal Backbone setup and initialize() is invoked as normal.
            Backbone.Model.apply(this, arguments);
        },
        /**
         * This parse override checks to see if a namespace was provided, and if so,
         * it will strip it out and return response[this._namespace
         * @param response
         * @param xhr
         * @return {*}
         */
        parse : function(response, xhr) {
            //If a namespace is defined you have to make sure that
            //it exists in the response; otherwise, an error will be
            //thrown.
            return (this._namespace && response[this._namespace]) ? response[this._namespace] 
                                                                  : response;
        },
        /**
         * In overriding toJSON, we check to see if a namespace was defined. If so,
         * then create a namespace node and assign the attributes to it. Otherwise,
         * just call the "super" toJSON.
         * @return {Object}
         */
        toJSON : function() {
            var respObj = {};
            var attr = Backbone.Model.prototype.toJSON.apply(this);
            if (this._namespace) {
                respObj[this._namespace] = attr;
            } else {
                respObj = attr;
            }
            return respObj;
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create and update operations on models call [`toJSON`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON) to produce the data for the server:

> **toJSON** `model.toJSON()`
>
> Return a copy of the model's *attributes* for JSON stringification. This can be used for persistence, serialization, or for augmentation before being handed off to a view.

You could provide your own `toJSON`:

```
toJSON: function() {
    return { SourceMachine: _(this.attributes).clone() };
}
```

That should make your server happy. Unfortunately, `toJSON` is also commonly used to provide data for your templates and you probably don't want the `SourceMachine` noise in there; if so, then add another method to prepare data for your templates:

```
// Or whatever you want to call it...
valuesForTemplate: function() {
    return _(this.attributes).clone();
}
```

That's what the standard `toJSON` method does internally.

Comment: Very cool. I knew there was an easy way to do this. You've given a couple of great ways of dealing with this! Thanks!

Comment: This works for PUT method but not for PATCH method as it doesn't call any function like `toJSON`.

Comment: @kevin: Did you figure out something for PATCH? I'm not actively using Backbone these days so I'm not sure what the best approach would be off the top of my head.

Comment: @muistooshort Overriding the `save()` function seems to work for PATCH method.